# Deploying and starting a webdriver test program on a remote windows vm from jenkins server

Tags: jenkins

I have a test program in Java for testing a web app using webdriver. It builds and runs in my local machine just fine.

Now, I need to build it in jenkins, then deploy and run it on a VM running on Windows (e.g. server 2008 R2).

Obviously, the test program doesn't work on jenkins as it needs to open a browser. This cannot be done under system account in Jenkins server. So I need to deploy it to a remote machine and somehow start the test.

I've heard this can be done using ssh for a linux box, but don't know how to do it for a windows VM.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed jenkins as service then you need to create a JNLP node in order to run your webdriver tests.

Follow the post for creating JNLP node and running your tests on that. 
http://qtp-help.blogspot.in/2013/09/setup-webdriver-maven-project-on-jenkins.html